# EditText не ловит клик

Tags: android

EditText не ловит клик. Точнее ловит, но со второго раза. Т.е. я загружаю приложение, тыкаю по ЭдитТексту в первый раз - ничего не происходит. Второй раз и далее, он делает, то, что я от него хочу. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: focus срабатывает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здравствуйте.

Посмотрите в сторону `editText.`**`setOnTouchListener`**`(new View.OnTouchListener()` или `editText`.**`setOnFocusChangeListener`**`(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()`.

Comment: да-да-да) с помощью  setOnTouchListener проблема и была решена)

Answer (score 1):

Может вам нужно счётчик кликов какой-нибудь организовать? Трэйсить пробовали, в консоль что-то  элементарное выводит при написании в методе обработчике сисаута?

Comment: при первом тыке в лог не выводит ничего. при втором и далее - всё нормально. просто причину хотелось бы выяснить.

Comment: код покажи

Comment: implements OnClickListener присутствует в коде объявления класса?
Метод onClick правильно переопределён?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: EditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
         
         

   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Log.w("RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR", "Клик сработал");
    
   }
         
        });

Comment: возможно, что при первом "щелчке" по этиттексту, вызывается некий иной метод этого эдитТекста. так как, по нему в первый раз необходимо тыкнуть именно 2 раза.

Comment: отличные теги, не могу не выделить

кинь код своего эдитТекста на леяуте

Comment: и вообще, зачем тебе на него вешать кликЛистенер? он определен там, что бы текст внутри писать

Comment: анимация по клику запускаю)))

Comment: Я заменила на setOnTouchListener. добавила пару условий, и всё стало на много лучше)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_TEXT = "ActionTextClick";

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main_layout);

    Intent active = new Intent(context, ExampleProvider.class);
    active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_TEXT);
    PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_refresh, actionPendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_TEXT)) {
        Log.i("onReceive", ACTION_WIDGET_TEXT);
    }
    }
Не забудьте добавить в манифест:

<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
                <action android:name="org.divenvrsk.widgets.ExampleProvider.ACTION_WIDGET_TEXT"/>

   </intent-filter>
```